# CSS Transform Element

Tags: css, transform, skew

Using the CSS `transform` property, how can I make a button like this:

[image]

I've tried playing with `skew`, `rotate`, `rotate3d` and `perspective` without luck. It feels as if I need to be a mathematician to understand some of these new properties

Comment: Why do you need it in css ?

Comment: Because there are multiple elements on the website using similar transformations with different widths and heights

Comment: Why not use SVG images?

Comment: Good idea Joel. I may have to resort to that, but I'd like to avoid it if possible because the designer has put a transformation on literally every block element of the site, so lots of different background colours etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to fiddle with rotating along all 3 axes, and skewing. Here's an example:

```css
div {
    perspective: 200px; 
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    line-height: 2.4;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div::before {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    background: #7fc552;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    transform: skew(-9deg) rotateX(-22deg) rotateY(-21deg) rotateZ(-9deg);
    /* Firefox seems to render this with pretty bad jagged edges.
       Add a transparent outline to fix that. */
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Here's a live demo: http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/Jvohk/

Comment: This is fantastic! I can use this to get the effect needed on other elements too. Thank you very much Joseph

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this shape, check the following tools and ways:

Image map:

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

Descriptiom: you upload a normal picture and you map the area where it should be clickable

---

Image mask:

http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Description: you create custom border shapes for the image you want to use

---

SVG:

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polygon.asp

Description: you create polygon vector with html to achieve the shape desired.